# String splitting and joining on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe containing devices and their corresponding firmware versions (e.g. 1.7.1.3). I'm trying to shorten the firmware version to only show three numbers (e.g. 1.7.1).

I know how to do this on a single string but how would I make it efficient for a large dataframe?

```
test = "1.2.3.4"
test = test.split(".")
'.'.join(test[0:-1])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#sample dataframe:
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'data': {0: '1.2.3.4', 1: '1.2.3.9', 2: '1.2.3.8'}})
```

For this you can use:

```
df['data']=df['data'].str.split('.').str[0:3].apply('.'.join)
```

**OR**

```
df['data']=df['data'].str[0:5]
```

**OR**

```
df['data']=df['data'].str[::-1].str.split('.',1).str[1].str[::-1]
```

**Performance:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This could be done by `extract` function of pandas too, could you please try following.

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.extract(r'^(\d+(?:\.\d+){2})', expand=True)
```

Simple explanation would be: using `extract` function of Pandas and mentioning regex in it to catch only first 3 digits as per OP's need.

---

---

Taking example of DataFrame used by Anurag Dabas here:

Let's say df is following:

```
    data
0   1.2.3.4
1   1.2.3.9
2   1.2.3.8
```

After running above code it will become like:

```
    data
0   1.2.3
1   1.2.3
2   1.2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way of doing it using `.replace`:

```sh
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': {0: '1.2.3.4', 1: '1.2.3.9', 2: '1.2.3.8'}})
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'\.[^.]*$', '')
print (df['data'])
```

**Output:**

```
0    1.2.3
1    1.2.3
2    1.2.3
Name: data, dtype: object
```

`.replace(r'\.[^.]*$', '')` matches last dot and text after that, which is replaced with an empty string.